# Nested List Iterator. Program doesn't terminates

Tags: java, iterator

Below is my program.

```
public class NewClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> cars = new ArrayList<String>();
        cars.add("Maruti");
        cars.add("Hundai");
        cars.add("Polo");
        Iterator<String> literate1 =  cars.iterator();
        while (literate1.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(literate1.next());
            literate1.remove();
            Iterator<String> literate2 =  cars.iterator();
            while (literate2.hasNext()){
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
Maruti
```

Just after printing this result, program doesn't terminates. Can you explain what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`literate2.hasNext()` always returns `true`. So `while` loop will never end.

Answer (score 2):

Please check the below code. It will work.

```
List<String> cars = new ArrayList<String>();
cars.add("Maruti");
cars.add("Hundai");
cars.add("Polo");
Iterator<String> literate1 =  cars.iterator();
while (literate1.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(literate1.next());
}
```

In your code, the inner while loop has the condition `literate2.hasNext()`. It's actually returning true all the time. For that reason, it's creating an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
while (literate2.hasNext()){
}
```

Infinite loop right there.  Until you call next(), hasNext() will always return true if there are more items.